# A part of my blender render is invisible?

Tags: rendering

[image: therender]

For some reason, a part of the render is invisible.

It might be the material (i didnt make it), but i don't know how to fix that

https://www.dropbox.com/s/k3o1mocp7xd9nsz/CarPaintMaterialPacked.blend?dl=0

The paint was taken from this but the color was changed a bit

https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=problem.blend

this is the problematic part of the object.

Comment: are you sure you've shared the good file?

Comment: yes im sure i have

Comment: @sairaajm. You didn't share the right file. [See this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sZmU.jpg)

Comment: if I press 0 to see through the camera I see an orange sphere, and when I render I also see an orange sphere, not what you show on your screenshot

Comment: yeah thats the color not the object, but when i use the color with a changed hue, the result is pictured.

Comment: @sairaajm We need need the original with the problem in order to help you.

Comment: I added the original, but for some reason, the color has to be added again.

Comment: it's a wrong link  ;)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114119/a-part-of-my-blender-render-is-invisible

Comment: I've answered to your question in your new topic, I don't understand the link between the 2 questions though...

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice