# A part of my blender render is invisible?

Tags: rendering

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x8uk3lrd4z56lbc/problemchild.blend?dl=0

If you render, the roof of the car becomes invisible.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your Normals are flipped, you have to select your car, go in Edit mode, select all, then ctrl N to recalculate.
- Two of your objects are not visible for render, go in the Outliner and click on the camera icons for your 2 planes, or in your scene press W > Clear All Restrict Render